# Display both images and text of email body in add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I want to populate all data of email in text box of containing multiple rows using apps script. I did this

```
function getCurrentMessage(event) {
  var accessToken = event.messageMetadata.accessToken;
  var messageId = event.messageMetadata.messageId;
  GmailApp.setCurrentMessageAccessToken(accessToken);
  return GmailApp.getMessageById(messageId);
}
```

And second method is

```
function getMessage(message) {
   var exp = message.getRawContent();
   var message = message.getBody();
   return message;
}
```

Last line of second method populated the message in text box, but if the email contain images then they are not shown--just some spaces.

Can any one have idea or another way to done it?

Comment: Why would a text box hold anything other than text?

Comment: @tehhowch because i send data of text box, and if tex box did not contain original data of email then how it;s possible to send..

Comment: Let's just look at what you've provided here: you show the message object retrieval, and then the retrieval of the body text (`message.getBody()`). You don't access any images. You access the raw content in `exp`, but do nothing with this. You don't show the code the calls `getMessage`, nor the code that constructs the UI. You need to edit this to [ask a better question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) with an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: In case you missed it: https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/concepts/widgets#text_formatting